# Regex expression to find all class definitions?

Tags: regex

I am using control shift F in sublime. I want to put a regular expression there that will show me all my class definitions across all files.

I want to do a regular expression for something like 
"class any amount of characters:"

so the regular expression should find something like

```
class EventProcessorMixin(BaseClass):
```

which is one of my classes. As well as another class like

```
class Event_process_locations_advance(GameEvent):
```

I tried

```
r"class [\w]*\((.*)\):"
```

and

```
/class [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\({0,1}.*\){0,1}:/
```

but neither worked.

Comment: Your regex works like this - https://regex101.com/r/TYhGEW/1. What is wrong with that? Why use `python` tag if you say you are using the regex in Sublime Text?

Comment: Just to be sure, did you enable searching with regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any character between "class" and ":" try:

```
class .*:
```